# WKWebView shows a cropped background and blank space after rotation on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, background, web, wkwebview

I'm migrating my app from UIWebView to WKWebView for iOS8.x (maintaining support for iOS7.x) users and I'm having a trouble with the website I'm displaying, because after rotating the iPad, it displays the content but the background seems somehow cropped and therefore there is a blank space after the bg.

However **as soon as I start scrolling the website, it fixes automatically by itself**. This blank effect also happens when I pass from landscape to portrait orientation, which leaves the right side of the website with the blank background.

Here's how I tryed solving the issue:

```
(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:
(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration (NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [_webView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}

(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [_webView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}
```

I've tried many things (reloading the background via JS, handling the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation and didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation methods as shown above) but have not been able to solve the issue, and **it only happens when using WKWebView, if I switch back to UIWebView, the website renders properly**.

I also tested the website on Safari for the very same device (an iPad2 with iOS 8.1.3) and it doesn't show the error, no matter how many times I rotate the iPad, so I'm sure it can be solved =). Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in WKWebKit that's usually triggered by HTML elements with `position: fixed` applied.  The only workaround I've found is to use `window.scrollTo()` to scroll the page by one pixel a few hundred miliseconds after a `resize` event.

Comment: Thanks Justin, it works for all pages that can be scrolled. Do you have a workaround for pages that don't scroll? I tried using the same concept, refreshing the background, however it didn't work...

Comment: @MSalazar What do you mean by "pages that don't scroll"?

Comment: I meant pages that because of a too-short content don't NEED to scroll, and therefore can't scroll. I suppose I could add "extra" empty content for those so that I force the page to be able to scroll but was wondering if there is another workaround for those?

Comment: @MSalazar None that I know of right now; adding the extra element to force scrolling is probably the only way.  Here's hoping this bug gets fixed soon!

Answer (score 2):

This save my life:

```
self.wkWebView.evaluateJavaScript("window.scrollBy(1, 1);window.scrollBy(-1, -1);", completionHandler: nil)
```

Add this line on wkwebview did finish navigation event!!

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while, but I got it working for pages without scroll:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
            setTimeout(function () {
                var vp = document.getElementsByName("viewport")[0],
                    vpContent = vp.content,
                    vpHack = ((window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth) ? window.screen.availHeight  / window.innerHeight : window.screen.availWidth / window.innerWidth) + 0.0001;
                vp.content = "user-scalable=no, initial-scale="+vpHack+", maximum-scale="+vpHack+", minimum-scale="+vpHack+",width=device-width";
                setTimeout(function(){vp.content=vpContent;},10);
            }, 500);
        }, true);
```

That's assuming you use viewport. it changes the viewport by 0.0001 for 10 milliseconds

I implemented it like this:

```
-(void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {
NSLog(@"###### FINISH");
[self.webView evaluateJavaScript:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"if (document.readyState==='complete'){ window.addEventListener('resize', function(){setTimeout(function () {var vp = document.getElementsByName('viewport')[0],vpContent = vp.content,vpHack = ((window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth) ? window.screen.availHeight  / window.innerHeight : window.screen.availWidth / window.innerWidth) + 0.0001; vp.content = 'user-scalable=no, initial-scale='+vpHack+', maximum-scale='+vpHack+', minimum-scale='+vpHack+',width=device-width';setTimeout(function(){vp.content=vpContent;},10);}, 500);}, true); } else { window.addEventListener('load', function(){window.addEventListener('resize', function(){setTimeout(function () {var vp = document.getElementsByName('viewport')[0],vpContent = vp.content,vpHack = ((window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth) ? window.screen.availHeight  / window.innerHeight : window.screen.availWidth / window.innerWidth) + 0.0001; vp.content = 'user-scalable=no, initial-scale='+vpHack+', maximum-scale='+vpHack+', minimum-scale='+vpHack+',width=device-width';setTimeout(function(){vp.content=vpContent;},10);}, 500);}, true);}, false );}"] completionHandler:nil];
```

}

Comment: I don't understand how this is supposed to execute after a rotation, that implementation looks like it executes after navigation to the page?

Answer (score 0):

I use `document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('style')).remove();`
to tickle my WKWebViews into redrawing after resize/rotate.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work... The first answer actually worked, but as I said had to add extra blank space in order to be able to scroll automatically. What I did was to scroll down and go back once the page was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The following workaround worked for me, but unfortunately only on the Simulator:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [super didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:fromInterfaceOrientation];

    // Workaround for WKWebView iOS 8 Rotation Bug
    // Official Fix (iOS 9): http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/169625
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] integerValue] == 8) {
        CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
        frame.size.width += 1;
        self.view.frame = frame;
        frame.size.width -= 1;
        self.view.frame = frame;
    }
}
```

After some experimenting I got it to work on the device too using the following steps:

- Keep two sets of AutoLayout constraints, the first one for the behavior you actually intend and the second with a small change (e.g. 1 point size difference)
- Whenever the orientation changes, apply the second set to the view, then, after 1 second, apply the first constraints set.

While this solution is far from ideal, it is the only one I found without manipulating the Javascript on the website. I tried to lower the delay, but in my tests I had to wait for at least 0.8 seconds.