# WKWebView web page aligns top left on IPA

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, storyboard, wkwebview

I am using WKWebView in my Objective C application to load a web view. When I run the app through XCode the page loads properly[Screenshot for running app from xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD8oT.png)

If I take an IPA and run it on device the webpage loads to the topleft of the WKWebView

[Screenshot for loading app using IPA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0xjW.png)

Comment: Please provide your question with code showing a reproducible example.

Comment: Just used this code in viewdidload method

 
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.testWebView loadRequest:request];

Comment: What is `testWebView ` and how is it configured?

Comment: There's also quite a few similar questions on SO that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489892/wkwebview-shows-a-cropped-background-and-blank-space-after-rotation-on-ipad , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34373155/content-of-webpage-is-cut-off-in-uiwebview , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58367393/wkwebview-on-macos-cuts-off-top

Comment: `testWebView` is a WKwebview. I tried configuring it using `storyboard` and manually in code

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not enough. We need details. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.